# Understanding example of a function

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I am having a lot of trouble understanding the solutions given to this problem. Could someone interpret it for me.

Give an example of a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that the taylor series of $f$ centered at $0$ converges for all $x$ and the taylor series converges to $f(x)$ for $x<1 $but not for $x>1$. Here is the answer word from word if someone could explain this.

In class $g(x)=e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}}, x \neq 0$, $g(x)=0$ if $x=0$. I know that this function is equal to its taylor series at $0$ only(my comment).

Here is what is confusing me

Answer: $g(x)=f(x-1)$ if $x \geq 1$ or $g(x)=0$ if $x<1$. So the taylor series is $\sum 0  x^k=0$ but $g(x) \neq 0$ for $x>1$. Could someone explain this solution. What is $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are several typos. The correct example is $g(x)=f(x-1)$ wher $f(x)=e^{-1/x^{2}}$ for $x \geq 0$ and $0$ for $x <0$. The Taylor series for $f$ converges  to $f(x)$ at $x$ iff $x \leq 0$. Hence, the Taylor series for $g$ converges  to $g(x)$ at $x$ iff $x \leq 1$.